# How can I subdivide a triangle so there is a vertex in the center of each triange?

Tags: modeling

For example, I have an icosahedron and I want to put a vertex in the middle of each face so I can make a dodecahedron later. However when i try to subdivide it it does the reasonable thing, to divide each into 4 equilateral triangles. Is there a way to do what I explained above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the *Poke* tool (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>):

[image]