# Bring vertices in/out of center of object?

Tags: modeling

Sort of like when you use poke (Alt + P), letting you drag the new vertices in or out. Only with this I don't want to create new vertices.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you want just scaling vertices ? Depending on the mesh you could change Pivot Point to scale accordingly from the center of selecttion.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that you are progressing from [How can I subdivide a triangle so there is a vertex in the center of each triange?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48624/how-can-i-subdivide-a-triangle-so-there-is-a-vertex-in-the-center-of-each-triang) ; Maybe what you want is to select a bunch of vertices then use <kbd>s</kbd> to scale.  The trick is that scale is relative to the pivot point which is usually Active Element.  Often this is good enough, but sometimes you'll have to pick Cursor, or something else.